# Problems parsing generated JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I got a JSON object that I have generated via Rails 3 (via my API). I need to either put a named surrounding tag around it or loose the first "layer". I know it sounds very strange, but I cannot loop it in the client.

This is the parsing code:

```
@results = RestClient.get "http://localhost:5000/emails?token=#{get_token}", :accept => :json
@array = JSON.parse(@results);
```

Turn this:

```
[
    {
        "email": {
            "created_at": "2011-03-02T12:23:59Z",
            "updated_at": "2011-03-02T12:23:59Z",
            "value_1": "intevisa@sss.com",
            "value_2": null,
            "id": 4,
            "value_3": null,
            "user_id": 1,
            "value_4": null,
            "desc": "intevisa",
            "privacy": null
        }
    },
    {
        "email": {
            "created_at": "2011-03-02T15:19:39Z",
            "updated_at": "2011-03-02T15:19:39Z",
            "value_1": "another@yahoo.com",
            "value_2": null,
            "id": 5,
            "value_3": null,
            "user_id": 1,
            "value_4": null,
            "desc": "Some text",
            "privacy": null
        }
    },
    {
        "email": {
            "created_at": "2011-03-02T15:20:17Z",
            "updated_at": "2011-03-02T15:20:17Z",
            "value_1": "my@email.com",
            "value_2": null,
            "id": 6,
            "value_3": null,
            "user_id": 1,
            "value_4": null,
            "desc": "Some text",
            "privacy": null
        }
    },
    {
        "email": {
            "created_at": "2011-03-02T15:21:03Z",
            "updated_at": "2011-03-02T15:21:03Z",
            "value_1": "An email@google.com",
            "value_2": null,
            "id": 7,
            "value_3": null,
            "user_id": 1,
            "value_4": null,
            "desc": "Hello world",
            "privacy": null
        }
    }
]
```

Into this:

```
[

        "email": {
            "created_at": "2011-03-02T12:23:59Z",
            "updated_at": "2011-03-02T12:23:59Z",
            "value_1": "intevisa@sss.com",
            "value_2": null,
            "id": 4,
            "value_3": null,
            "user_id": 1,
            "value_4": null,
            "desc": "intevisa",
            "privacy": null
        },

        "email": {
            "created_at": "2011-03-02T15:19:39Z",
            "updated_at": "2011-03-02T15:19:39Z",
            "value_1": "another@yahoo.com",
            "value_2": null,
            "id": 5,
            "value_3": null,
            "user_id": 1,
            "value_4": null,
            "desc": "Some text",
            "privacy": null
        },

        "email": {
            "created_at": "2011-03-02T15:20:17Z",
            "updated_at": "2011-03-02T15:20:17Z",
            "value_1": "my@email.com",
            "value_2": null,
            "id": 6,
            "value_3": null,
            "user_id": 1,
            "value_4": null,
            "desc": "Some text",
            "privacy": null
        },

        "email": {
            "created_at": "2011-03-02T15:21:03Z",
            "updated_at": "2011-03-02T15:21:03Z",
            "value_1": "An email@google.com",
            "value_2": null,
            "id": 7,
            "value_3": null,
            "user_id": 1,
            "value_4": null,
            "desc": "Hello world",
            "privacy": null
        }

]
```

This is how I try to loop through it in the client.

```
<% @array['email'].each do |item| %>

    <%= item['value_1'] %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in config > initializers > wrap_parameters.rb

```
# Enable parameter wrapping for JSON. You can disable this by setting :format to an empty array.
ActionController::Base.wrap_parameters format: [:json]

# Disable root element in JSON by default.
if defined?(ActiveRecord)
  ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false
end
```

By setting the "include_root_in_json" to false, it should get you the desired output